# Is there a way to get the character lengths of each word of a string in Geometry Nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, text-object

[image]

I want the character length of each word of a string. Is this possible procedurally?

My idea was to divide them into lines, but I can't get to separate the lines into individual strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that sets the size of the first letter of each word (line) based on the length of the word:

[image]

The tab is added at the end, because newline characters count, and there's no newline character at the last line. This is also why $1$ is subtracted from the calculated value, because you probably don't want to count the characters together with the newline character…

[image]

[image]